# Finding time complexity of a simple function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I am trying to wrap my head around Big O. I have written two versions of a function that finds the "majority element" in an array (i.e. the element that occurs more than n/2 times where n is the length of the array). For example, if the input array is [2,2,1,1,1,2,2], the result is 2.
My questions are:

1. Is version 1 worst-case O(n^2)? [I think it is because countInstances is probably O(n) and the main function might end up calling it n times]
2. Is version 2 O(n)? [This probably has something to do with using Map, but I'm not 100% clear about that]

Any clarification would be highly appreciated!

**Version 1**

```js
function countInstances(arr, instance) {
    return arr.filter((el)=>el===instance).length
}


function MajorityElement(arr){
    let uniques = new Set(arr)
    let threshold = Math.floor(arr.length/2)
    for (el of uniques){
        if (countInstances(arr, el)>threshold){
            return el
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

**Version 2**

```js
function getFrequencies(arr){
    let freqs = new Map
    for (el of arr){
        if (freqs.has(el)){
            freqs.set(el, freqs.get(el)+1)
        } else{
            freqs.set(el,1)
        }   
    }
    return freqs
}

function majorityElement(arr){
    let freqMap = getFrequencies(arr)
    let n = Math.floor(arr.length/2)
    
    for (let key of freqMap.keys()) {
        if (freqMap.get(key)>n){
            return key
        }
    }
    return null

}
```

Comment: Yeah first one in worst case would be O(n^2) when all entries are unique. Second one is O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. `.filter` will always iterate over every element of an array, so if the callback is `O(1)` (which it is in this case), the `.filter` operation is `O(n)`. `countInstances` is `O(n)`.

You call `countInstances` inside a loop:

```
for (el of uniques){
    if (countInstances(arr, el)>threshold){
```

adding another dimension, so you get `O(n ^ 2)`.

In the second code, there are no nested loops. The only loops are:

```
function getFrequencies(arr){
    let freqs = new Map
    for (el of arr){
        // linear operations
```

and

```
for (let key of freqMap.keys()) {
    // linear operations
```

so it's `O(n)`.